# Wzone Lite AWS connection with woocommerce

Tags: amazon-product-api, affiliate

```
Amazon Error: ErrCode = 1 | ErrMsg = [[ Amazon API v5:
http status code = 403
http msg = [403] Client error: `POST https://webservices.amazon.in/paapi5/searchitems` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"__type":"com.amazon.paapi5#AccessDeniedException","Errors":[{"Code":"AccessDenied","Message":"The Access Key Id AKIAII (truncated...)
http x-amzn-RequestId = 512c0bb2-9409-4f35-aa46-579b7a289c9d
errcode = AccessDenied
errmsg = The Access Key Id AKIAIIIXUUSHKX2VX6AA is not enabled for accessing Product Advertising API. Please sign up for Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/assoc_credentials/home. ]]
WooCommerce Amazon Affiliates was not able to connect to Amazon with the specified AWS Key Pair and Associate ID. Please triple-check your AWS Keys and Associate ID.
```

Comment: Removed the image as it contains your secret key which should be kept secret